# How do I tag people in comments/questions?

Tags: discussion

I've asked several questions already and when someone answers I want to thank them but I don't know how to tag them in a post/comment. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about general Stack Exchange Functionality which should be asked on  http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Memor-X There's actually a vote option for that in close > off topic > other site > meta.

Comment: Thank you for you advice I will do just that and close the question

Comment: @SevenSidedDie i was sure that was for the Arqade Meta? not general meta

Comment: @Irishterminator0 also you can "thank" users by upvoting their answers and/or accepting the best answer, but you will need to log into your [other account](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/106181/irishterminator0) (assuming it is you given the thank you answer)

Comment: @Memor-X: Questions about general stack exchange functionality, like this one, are allowed on all meta sites, not just meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

You can't comment on others' posts yet because that's a [privilege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that's only unlocked after earning [50 reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comments aren't really for thanking, though, and that's why they're not available until someone's had the chance to learn how the site works. (They exist so that posts can be discussed temporarily when they need fixing, correcting, or clarifying.) Instead of leaving comments to thank people, show your appreciation by [accepting the most helpful answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), or by upvoting good answers once you've unlocked the [upvote privilege by earning 15 reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).